Play Install Referrer Integration SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
I am trying to integrate the install referrer support via the Play Install Referrer Library. The app works fine as a debug build, but when testing the flow in a release build, the app crashes with the abovementioned error. As the error is happening in a release build, the initial assumption is that it can be because of an issue with R8/Progard but nothing related to this is mentioned in the official docs.

The error is indeed due to the R8 obfuscation of the interface name in the Play Install Referrer library. The error was fixed after adding the following rules in proguard-rules.pro:
# Keep Install Referrer Library
-keep class com.android.installreferrer.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.finsky.** { *; }

# Keep classes needed for AIDL communication if necessary
-keep class **.aidl.** { *; }

The last aidl rule is added just as a cautionary measure and I'm not sure if it is required. The finsky rule is for a package included in the Install Referrer library and contains the interface for AIDL communication.
